# Create plot for random walk

Tags: graphing-functions, random-walk

[image]

Is there any tool, that can create such a plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position of a randomly walking object is given by:
$$
S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i
$$where in its simplest form, it is assumed that $X_i$s are iid and $\Pr\{X_i=1\}=\Pr\{X_i=-1\}={1\over 2}$. To sketch $S_n$ in terms of $n$, you can consider the following code blocks:

MATLAB

```
N = 70;                     % Number of steps
X = 2*(rand(1,N)<0.5)-1;    % For producing i.i.d. X random variables
S = cumsum(X);              % For the random walk sequence
stem(S)
title('Random walk vs time')
```

[image]

Python

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 70                                # Number of steps
X = 2*(numpy.random.rand(N)<0.5)-1    # For producing i.i.d. X random variables
S = numpy.cumsum(X)                   # For the random walk sequence
plt.stem(S)
plt.title('Random walk vs time',fontsize=14)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to mark different areas of the plot as in the picture above. How can I get dotted lines in my graph?

Comment: You're welcome. You can mark different areas inside the code main block using 'rectangle' and 'text' commands (passing proper values for their position and size), but it is also possible to do it after the figure was produced by manually manipulating the details in paint (or something like that). You can use "plt.stem(S,linefmt='k:')" instead of "plt.stem(S)" to obtain dotted ,dashed or any other desire line format.

Comment: If I manipulate it in an other programm, doesn't look weird, because font is different for example?

Comment: Well, preserving the basic concepts is the most important thing, but you may change the details a little.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I appreciate it very much:)